# Import fbx model from unity

Tags: import, unity, external-applications

Is it possible to import an fbx model, so that I can edit models from unity in blender?

I tried and nothing worked, when I open the file I see the default cube when opening blender.

Comment: No. I didnt see this question

Comment: And its answer dont work

Comment: Exactly what happened? Were there any error messages? (Just saying "it doesn't work" doesn't really give us any clues..)

Answer (score 0):

There is an fbx Import-Export add-on, have you tried it?

[image]

This could be helpfull to :

http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?274687-Another-FBX-Importer-Exporter-addon

Comment: Note that it's enabled by default and is accessible in the import menu.

Comment: Thank you.But thats what i said isnt working. I solved it by converting the fbx to an older version using Autodesk FBX Converter x64 2013 and only after that the import worked

Comment: that addon seems gone forever, but 2.76 has importer bundled, I will try @sagicoh tip! I managed to import a .obj as wavefront on 2.76 after exporting it to obj thru "Autodesk FBX Converter x64 2013", but textures normals are weird, but I think it may be easy to fix.